# How to load gltf scene in threejs using ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, three.js, internet-explorer-11, gltf

I have done a simple html to load a gltf model using three.js and their gltfloader.js and it works perfectly on Mozilla, but it doesn't show up on ie11 even though it through no errors. I have tried using es6-promise pollyfill but it doesn't seem to work. I need it to work on internet explorer. I leave the code down here, it's mostly a copy-paste from an example code.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <title>My first three.js app</title>
            <style>
                body { margin: 0; }
                canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="js/three.js"></script>
            <script src="js/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
            <script src="js/OrbitControl.js"></script>
            <script src="js/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/es6-promise.js"></script>
            <script src="js/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>      

            <script>
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
                var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                controls.screenSpacePanning = true;

                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xefe3a7 );
                camera.position.z = 5;
                controls.update();

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
                var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( cube );

                var animate = function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                    renderer.render( scene, camera );
                };

                    light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xbbbbff, 0x444422 );
                    light.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
                    scene.add( light );

                // Instantiate a loader
                var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();


                // Load a glTF resource
                loader.load(
                    // resource URL
                    'DUCK/Duck.gltf',
                    // called when the resource is loaded
                    function ( gltf ) {

                        scene.add( gltf.scene );

                        gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
                        gltf.scene; // THREE.Scene
                        gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Scene>
                        gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
                        gltf.asset; // Object

                    },
                    // called while loading is progressing
                    function ( xhr ) {

                        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

                    },
                    // called when loading has errors
                    function ( error ) {

                        console.log( 'An error happened' );

                    }

                );
                animate();
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**EDIT**: The box is just a reference to show that only the gltf model is the one not working, the box shows normaly on ie11.

**EDIT 2**: The [gltf loader example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=loader#webgl_loader_gltf) from the threejs site doesn't work either on ie11. Does this mean that the loader is not compatible with ie11?

Comment: Other than nothing showing up, what else happens? Are any of the three functions called, do they log anything? It does seem strange that you have three Promise polyfill scripts all on the same page.

Comment: Well, I am no developer so I was trying different Promise polyfill because I wasn't sure about how they work. The three functions work all well because the box is shown as expected and the log throws nothing. As I said, it works perfectly on Mozilla but the loaded gltf doesn't show (or it shows transparent) on ie11.

Comment: FYI: IE11 shows these warnings on the console, but it has nothing to do with the gltf loader
THREE.WebGLRenderer: WEBGL_depth_texture extension not supported.
THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_half_float extension not supported.
THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_half_float_linear extension not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

1. import ES6 support polyfill in html

   `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>`
2. if your page still doesn't show the gltf model,you may need to do this:
   change the function **parse** in GLTFLoader.js

   `var json = JSON.parse(content)`

   to

   `var json = JSON.parse(content.trim())`

   *myBrowser:IE 11.0.9600.17843IS*