# Is the gltf loader from three.js incompatible with ie11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, three.js, internet-explorer-11, gltf

I have been trying to load gltf in three.js scenes using the loader but it doesn't work on ie11 whereas [it is said that it does on their web site](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader). Also, [the gltf loader examples don't work either](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=loader#webgl_loader_gltf) (on internet explorer). Can anybody confirm that this is the case and, if so, please update the information about the browser compatibility of the loader?

**EDIT:** I have already tried using ES6 Promises polyfill as in my example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558365/how-to-load-gltf-scene-in-threejs-using-ie11) I posted a month ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLTFLoader is compatible with IE11, but requires that you "polyfill" certain features that are missing in IE11. In practice, that means you must include a script that adds the Promise feature, which IE11 does not have by default.

If that isn't working, I would suggest filing an issue on the three.js github issues, it may be a bug.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have already tried using ES6 Promises polyfill as in my example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558365/how-to-load-gltf-scene-in-threejs-using-ie11) I posted a month ago. If it's a bug, I would like you please to post it on the github because I am not a developer and I don't want to put junk content in github using incorrect wording.

Comment: Ok, yes it sounds likely that either the loader or the docs are incorrect. I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14831

Comment: There was the issue about gtfl loader, promises, and docs: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12683

Comment: Per the note in the new issue, this is working correctly for me when including the polyfill script I mention there. Could you try again, including only that specific Promise polyfill script, and not the others? If that doesn't work, I may need to know which model you're using. The DamagedHelmet one worked for me. The other issue was resolved by adding the polyfill, as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that specific Promise polyfill and inform you with the result. It would be nice tho to add that to the gltf loader examples published on the three.js site so they can be viewed on ie11. 

**EDIT:** Ok I have tried that and is still not working. The model I am using is a duck.gltf model example I downloaded from the web, but no mattter what model I use, it won't work. If needed, I can upload the html, js and model files somewhere in order for you to detect the issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: I got this error on the es6-promise.auto.js, line 1064, column 21:

SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier

Answer (score 1):

According to [three.js docs, GLTFLoader: Browser compatibility](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader):

```
GLTFLoader relies on ES6 Promises, which are not supported in IE11.
To use the loader in IE11, you must include a polyfill providing a Promise replacement.
```

gltf loader is incompatible with IE11, but it's possible to to make it work with IE11 with polyfills for ES6 promises.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Although I have already tried ES6 promises polyfills and the scene continues not showing the gltf model. I [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558365/how-to-load-gltf-scene-in-threejs-using-ie11) you to a question I posted a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

if your page doesn't show the gltf models after import ES6 polyfill,you may need to do this:

change the **parse** function in **GLTFLoader.js**

```
var json = JSON.parse(content)
```

to

```
var json = eval('('+content+')')
```

it works for me.

Comment: answer updates:in the above,maybe do not need to use `eval` method.you can just change `var json = JSON.parse(content)` to `var json = JSON.parse(content.trim())`